# grpc one client, multiple servers

Tags: go, grpc

I have a grpc client in my service that primarily makes calls to a corresponding server within the same cluster.
There are some situations were Im needing to fan out the client call to services across all clusters.  A few approaches Im thinking is .

1. Create a client for each seperate client connection
2. dynamically change the connection at the time of calling it
3. Use middleware to do the above.

None of these really sound good to me though, I cant quite understand how middleware would work as its typically passing on an invoker to the next middleware interceptor so fanning out a request seems like its not possible as its not going to deal with multiple responses?

Dynamically changing the connection for each call I think can be messed up if its being used concurrently somewhere

Is there a best practise pattern I should be doing here? Having 10 different clients seems janky?

Comment: > Having 10 different clients seems janky?

What do you mean by this? Are these clients all talking to the same host? If so, you can reuse a *grpc.ClientConn and wrap it with the specific clients. But if you're talking to services that are all unrelated, there's nothing wrong with having multiple clients.

Comment: the client config is otherwise the same, and gets used in one processor, just the ClientConn changes to point to the service in the seperate host.  So it seems like there would be a lot of duplication, or Im maintaining a map of clients or something.  Seems simpler if I could hold multiple ClientConns within the single client and just updated it for calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "client config"? In gRPC terms, are these all the same `service` running on different hosts?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Awesome — thanks for the clarification. It's a somewhat niche use-case as most people rely on service routing to only talk to a subset of instances. We happen to do something similar and built a `ConnectionManager` that will keep connections around in a pool. I can share a snippet of what the implementation looks like in an answer when I get a moment. It'd at least clean up your call-sites. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand, but a `ConnectionManager` suggested above would work, but if you're looking for a more scalable solution, xDS might be of interest to you - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/grpc_xds_features.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a niche use which is probably why it feels weird. But you do need a distinct connection for every host you are communicating with. Swapping them via an interceptor feels wrong.

You can build a "connection manager" type that handles this for you, if you want. It comes in handy for us — though it's more code than a list of connections. It might not fit your use-case depending on how simple your program is.

Here is a very stripped down version. I hope it helps:

```golang
// Example Usage
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    addrs := []string{"hostA:20023", "hostB:20023", "hostC:20023"}
    mgr := NewConnectionManager()
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if err := mgr.Call(ctx, addr, doThing); err != nil {
            // handle
        }
    }
}

func doThing(ctx context.Context, conn *Connection) error {
    client := pb.YourClient(conn)
    return client.Method(&pb.MethodRequest{})
}


// Types

type CallFn func(contex.Context, *Connection)

type Connection struct {
    once    sync.Once
    manager *ConnectionManager
    *grpc.ClientConn
}

func (c *Connection) Close() error {
    var err error
    c.once.Do(func() {
        // Remove from the source manager on close
        err = c.manager.CloseConnection(c.ClientConn.Target())
    })
    return err
}

type ConnectionManager struct {
    mu     sync.RWMutex
    conns  map[string]*Connection
}

func NewConnectionManager() *ConnectionManager {
    return &ConnectionManager{conns: map[string]*Connection{}}
}

func (m *ConnectionManager) Call(ctx context.Context, address string, fn CallFn) error {
    conn, err := m.Connect(ctx, address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // You could have exponential retry / backoff up to N times
    return fn(ctx, conn)
}

func (m *ConnectionManager) Connect(ctx context.Context, address string) (*Connection, error) {

    conn := m.connection(address)
    if conn != nil {
        return conn, nil
    }

    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    // Double check if we have a connection
    if conn := m.conns[address]; conn != nil {
        return conn, nil
    }

    // Create a new underlying client connection
    cc, err := m.newConnection(ctx, address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Wrap the underlying connection
    conn = &Connection{
        ClientConn: cc,
        manager:    m,
    }
    m.conns[address] = conn

    return conn, nil
}

func (m *ConnectionManager) newConnection(ctx context.Context, address string) (*grpc.ClientConn, error) {
    return grpc.DialContext(ctx, address,
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
        grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(...),
    )
}

func (m *ConnectionManager) Close() {
    // Close all connections
    m.mu.Lock()
    for address, conn := range m.conns {
        if err := conn.ClientConn.Close(); err != nil {
            // Log / handle
        }
    }
    m.conns = m.conns[:0]
    m.mu.Unlock()

}

func (m *ConnectionManager) CloseConnection(address string) error {
    return m.closeConnection(address)
}

func (m *ConnectionManager) closeConnection(address string) (err error) {
    m.mu.Lock()
    if conn, ok := m.conns[address]; ok {
        err = conn.ClientConn.Close()
        delete(m.conns, address)
    }
    m.mu.Unlock()
    return
}
```